# Как вUnity 3d синхронизовать генерируемую карту через photon pun 2

Tags: unity3d

Проблема с синхронизацией рандомно генерируемой карты через photon pun 2. Карта при старте генерируется сразу у одного игрока , а потом у второго генерируется уже своя.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class LaboratoryGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    PhotonView view;

    public bool GenerateOnStart = true;
    [Range(3, 100)]
    public int RoomCount = 9;
    public LayerMask CellLayer;

    public GameObject InsteadDoor;
    public GameObject[] DoorPrefabs;
    public Cell[] CellPrefabs;

    private void Start()
    {
        view = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        if (GenerateOnStart) StartCoroutine(StartGeneration());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
            view.RPC("StartGeneration", RpcTarget.All);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    IEnumerator StartGeneration()
    {
        List<Transform> CreatedExits = new List<Transform>();
        Cell StartRoom = Instantiate(CellPrefabs[Random.Range(0, CellPrefabs.Length)], Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
        for (int i = 0; i < StartRoom.Exits.Length; i++) CreatedExits.Add(StartRoom.Exits[i].transform);
        StartRoom.TriggerBox.enabled = true;

        int limit = 1000, roomsLeft = RoomCount - 1;
        while (limit > 0 && roomsLeft > 0)
        {
            limit--;

            Cell selectedPrefab = Instantiate(CellPrefabs[Random.Range(0, CellPrefabs.Length)], Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);

            int lim = 100;
            bool collided;
            Transform selectedExit;
            Transform createdExit; // из списка созданных входов

            selectedPrefab.TriggerBox.enabled = false; // чтобы сам себя не проверял на наличие нахлеста ВЫКЛЮЧИЛ

            do
            {
                lim--;

                createdExit = CreatedExits[Random.Range(0, CreatedExits.Count)];
                selectedExit = selectedPrefab.Exits[Random.Range(0, selectedPrefab.Exits.Length)].transform;

                // rotation
                float shiftAngle = createdExit.eulerAngles.y + 180 - selectedExit.eulerAngles.y;
                selectedPrefab.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, shiftAngle, 0)); // выходы повернуты друг напротив друга

                // position
                Vector3 shiftPosition = createdExit.position - selectedExit.position;
                selectedPrefab.transform.position += shiftPosition; // выходы состыковались

                // check
                Vector3 center = selectedPrefab.transform.position + selectedPrefab.TriggerBox.center.z * selectedPrefab.transform.forward
                    + selectedPrefab.TriggerBox.center.y * selectedPrefab.transform.up
                    + selectedPrefab.TriggerBox.center.x * selectedPrefab.transform.right; // selectedPrefab.TriggerBox.center
                Vector3 size = selectedPrefab.TriggerBox.size / 2f; // half size
                Quaternion rot = selectedPrefab.transform.localRotation;
                collided = Physics.CheckBox(center, size, rot, CellLayer, QueryTriggerInteraction.Collide);

                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

            } while (collided && lim > 0);

            selectedPrefab.TriggerBox.enabled = true; // ВКЛЮЧИЛ

            if (lim > 0)
            {
                roomsLeft--;

                for (int j = 0; j < selectedPrefab.Exits.Length; j++) CreatedExits.Add(selectedPrefab.Exits[j].transform);

                CreatedExits.Remove(createdExit);
                CreatedExits.Remove(selectedExit);

                Instantiate(DoorPrefabs[Random.Range(0, DoorPrefabs.Length)], createdExit.transform.position, createdExit.transform.rotation);
                DestroyImmediate(createdExit.gameObject);
                DestroyImmediate(selectedExit.gameObject);
            }
            else DestroyImmediate(selectedPrefab.gameObject);

            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }

        // instead doors
        for (int i = 0; i < CreatedExits.Count; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(InsteadDoor, CreatedExits[i].position, CreatedExits[i].rotation);
            DestroyImmediate(CreatedExits[i].gameObject);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Тут как будто обычный `Random` используется...

Answer (score 0):

```js
 private void Start()
    {
        if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
          StartCoroutine(StartGeneration());
    }

// удалить
private void Update()
{
        view.RPC("StartGeneration", RpcTarget.All);
}

[PunRPC]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]